# how to remediate CVE-2022-42889 in graphdb-free-9.11.1

Tags: graphdb

We using graphdb-free-9.11.1. To remediate CVE-2022-42889, Can we replace commons-text-1.9.jar with commons-text-1.10.0.jar?

Comment: In GraphDB 9.11.5 this vulnerability is not present.

Comment: Oh, thanks!. Any chance you have a link for 9.11.5?

Answer (score 0):

For the free version of GraphDB, instead of 9.11.5, better consider upgrading to the latest 10.1.4. The commons.text is version 1.10.0. As I don't know your environment, you can request a free version from here https://www.ontotext.com/products/graphdb/download/.